# Kable cell_spec conditional formatting not working correctly.

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, kableextra, kable

```
grid %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {format(x, digits = 2, big.mark = ",", 
decimal.mark = ".")}) %>%
  mutate(
seven_day_unique_viewers = cell_spec(seven_day_unique_viewers, italic = (Sys.Date() - as.Date(grid$debut_date, "%B %d, %Y") < 7)),
seven_day_rating = cell_spec(seven_day_rating, italic = (Sys.Date() - as.Date(grid$debut_date, "%B %d, %Y") < 7))
  ) %>%
kable(row.names=FALSE, col.names=col_names, align='c',format.args = 
list(decimal.mark = ".", big.mark = ",", justify = c("centre")),escape=TRUE) %>%
 kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("bordered", "hover","condensed"), 
full_width = F,font_size = 13) %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "11em") %>%
  column_spec(3, width = "10em") %>%
  row_spec(row_highlight, background = "yellow")
```

Not sure what is going on here and any advice would be appreciated. I confirmed that my if condition evaluates correctly.

Comment: change escape = T to F?

Comment: Hi Hao. Yes, the escape=FALSE will eliminate the HTML from showing in the table. Unfortunately, that's not my problem. My problem is that ALL items are being italicized and the conditional statement isn't working correctly. I noticed the following error message also: 2: In if (italic) cell_style <- paste(cell_style, "font-style: italic;") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (italic) cell_style <- paste(cell_style, "font-style: italic;") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @Hao . I just tried a few more tests and that error message is for sure the reason that there is a problem. It's determining the entire Italicize based on the evaluation of only the first element. Thus if it's T everything is Italicized and if it's F everything isn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I said yesterday, there was a bug in current CRAN version that causes this behavior. You should install from github for the dev version.

Comment: @Hao you really are the best. My sincere apologies. I was completely lost yesterday and didn't really understand what you were trying to tell me when you wanted me to reinstall. You're newest version has fixed the issue and we're good to go. Thanks so much.